# Can thaumcraft golems despawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I play modded minecraft  1.7.10 (dw20 modpack) and I set up a farm with Thaumcraft golems to collect the food. They disappeared. Did something or someone kill them? Did they despawn?

Chunk loaders are not allowed. Instead this server has chunkloading blocks, you pay for every loaded tick.

Comment: Thaumcraft golems farming food or iron golems farmed for iron?

Comment: food lol such an old question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've updated the question and retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Thaumcraft golems are not meant to despawn. However, the modded minecraft environment has multiple components, written by hobbiest developers, so the possibility of bugs are high.

Golems, when they do despawn, are typically found to do so if the version of Forge is not up to date, or, more likely (and especially on servers) if a non-forge based server is being used; i.e. Craftbukkit, kCauldron etc. as those are servers are notoriously buggy with a lot of mods, including Thaumcraft due to the mod developers are developing against a plain forge environment and don't have time to test against every server stack.

Thaumcraft golems are immune to most sources of environmental damage; they typically do not suffocate in trees, get damaged by cacti, drown or any of the other common hazards associated with operating farms, fishing or anything else that golems do.

All the reports of golem despawning that I have seen have pointed to a rare condition caused when the golem moves between a chunk and an unloaded chunk and the chunks are saved in the wrong order, so if this is a particular problem on your server you should be able to mitigate it by ensuring golems never cross chunk boundries.

Answer (score 0):

When the world is unloaded and loaded back in, if the golem is in a chunk that has not been loaded yet (the golem is out of the player's chunk loading range), it may fall to the ground and suffocate when the chunk is loaded.

The solution is to keep the chunk loaded with chunk loaders.

Comment: I explain in edit.

Comment: @technikfe you didn't explain anything.